# Need help with test class for code coverage on AccountContactRelation Object

Tags: apex, trigger

I've been working as an admin for my org for the last few months. After my move to Lightning, we needed to use the AccountContactRelation object to be able to mark a contact as the primary contact on the account. I needed a trigger to be able to prevent multiple primary contacts from being checked.

I was able to use the code below and it functions perfectly in my Sandbox environment when I tested it, however it's receiving a 0% code coverage, thus I can't deploy it to Prod. Based on reading and messing around, I was able to sort-of create a test-class, but I'm stuck on where to go from here as I have zero dev experience (except HTML/CSS).

I'd appreciate any help I can get! Thank you!

Trigger code that works in Sandbox:

```
 Trigger PreventMultiplePrimaryContacts on AccountContactRelation (Before Insert, Before Update) {

    List<AccountContactRelation> recordsToProcess = New List<AccountContactRelation>();
    List<Id> accountIds = New List<Id>();
    List<Id> contactIds = New List<Id>();


    If(Trigger.isBefore && (Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate)) {
        For(AccountContactRelation EveryRelationshipRecord : Trigger.New) {
            If(EveryRelationshipRecord.Primary__c == TRUE) {
                recordsToProcess.add(EveryRelationshipRecord);
                accountIds.add(EveryRelationshipRecord.AccountId);
                contactIds.add(EveryRelationshipRecord.ContactId);
            }
        }
    }

    List<AccountContactRelation> existingRecords = [
        Select id, ContactId, AccountId, Primary__c
        FROM AccountContactRelation
        WHERE Primary__c = TRUE
            AND Id !=: recordsToProcess
            AND AccountId =: accountIds
    ];


    If(recordsToProcess.isEmpty())    return;

    For(AccountContactRelation junctionObj :recordsToProcess ) {
        For(AccountContactRelation EveryExistingRecord : existingRecords) {
            If(junctionObj.AccountId == EveryExistingRecord.AccountId) {
                junctionObj.addError('There is already a Primary Contact for this Account. Please uncheck the other contact as primary before continuing.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class code that doesn't work:

```
@isTest
private class TestAccountContactRelation {
     @isTest static void TestAccountContactRelation() {
         Account acct = new Account(
             Name='HelloWorld'
         );

         insert acct;

         Contact con = new Contact(
             AccountId = acct.id,
             lastname = 'testdata', 
             firstname ='testdata1'
         );

         insert con; 

         Contact con1 = new Contact(
             AccountId = acct.id,
             lastname = 'testdata2', 
             firstname ='testdata2'
         );

         insert con1; 

         AccountContactRelation acctcr = new AccountContactRelation(
             AccountId = acct.id, 
             ContactId = con.id, 
             Primary__c = TRUE
         );

         insert acctcr;

         Test.startTest();

         acctcr.Primary__c = True;
         update con;

         Test.stopTest();

         system.asserts(acctcr.AccountId,acct.Id);
     }
}
```

Comment: There is no way this code compiled. Did it save successfully? Usually, you will get better help from the community if you paste any error messages *verbatim* into your post.

Comment: I agree with Adrian, you're most likely getting 0% coverage because you have another error somewhere else. If a test class fails it won't provide the coverage you need. I think you need to re-word your question to be more inline with your actual issue.

Comment: Specifically, this code should have failed to save with a fairly obvious error message like *Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void asserts(Id, Id) from the type System*.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use the below test method. It will give you the code coverage as well as cover the intention of the code(which is very important).

```
@isTest
public class TestAccountContactRelation {
    @isTest 
    static void TestAccountContactRelation() {

        Account acct = new Account(Name='HelloWorld');
        insert acct;

        Contact con = new Contact(AccountId = acct.id,lastname = 'testdata' , firstname ='testdata1');
        insert con; 

        Contact con1 = new Contact(AccountId = acct.id,lastname = 'testdata2' , firstname ='testdata2');
        insert con1; 

        AccountContactRelation acctcr = new AccountContactRelation(AccountId = acct.id, ContactId = con.id, Primary__c = TRUE);
        insert acctcr;

        List<AccountContactRelation> all = [SELECT ID, AccountId, ContactId, Primary__c FROM AccountContactRelation];
        System.assertEquals(1, all.size());
        System.assertEquals(acct.id, all.get(0).AccountId);
        System.assertEquals(con.id, all.get(0).ContactId);
        System.assertEquals(True, all.get(0).Primary__c);

        AccountContactRelation acctcr1 = new AccountContactRelation(AccountId = acct.id, ContactId = con1.id, Primary__c = TRUE);
        insert acctcr1;
        all = [SELECT ID, AccountId, ContactId, Primary__c FROM AccountContactRelation];
        System.assertEquals(2, all.size());
        /* check for AccountContactRelation record with Primary__c = false and also check for the error message */     

    }
}
```

Few comments

- Use Trigger Handler and more your code into Handler function. Don't write your business logic inside trigger. Read: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers
- Read this trailhead module on Apex Test class. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing

Comment: We have a *teach a man to fish* philosophy here, and you're just giving the OP a completed solution while teaching them nothing. It's not a free consulting site, and code dumps are frowned upon. Additionally, your assertions entirely neglect useful error messages.

Comment: Sorry for this. I tried to help him giving him the direction on how to write test classes and intentionally neglecting error message. Covering that will give him 100% code coverage. That is why I have given few links at the bottom of my post so that he can learn and implement the rest of the stuff. Anyway thank you @AdrianLarson for your feedback.

Comment: Thank you! What exactly does the all.get(0) and all.size() syntax actually doing?

Comment: all.size() will return the size of the list and all.get(0) will return the first element from the list which in this case your first AccountContactRelation record.

Answer (score 4):

When you update a record in the database, the in-memory record is not automatically updated. You need to query the record back again to see how it looks in the database.

```
acctcr = [select AccountId from accountcontactrelation where id = :acctcr.Id];
system.assertequals(acctcr.AccountId,acct.Id);
```

Please note that the method is `System.assertEquals`, not `System.asserts`. There are several different versions of assert methods you can call, which you can read about in the [System](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) namespace.